# what is the best way to save videos in a sql server?

Tags: php, sql

what is the best way to save videos in a sql server ?
i want to make a web app to save videos to the server and then retrive it back when needed

Comment: That's not really something you'd store in sql server.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How is storing a video different than storing a image/text/photo/spreadsheet/any-binary-file? Is the question about whether it's good to save them in the database? Is it about the type of the column to save them? Is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter which programming language you should follow :

- Store video on File server
- Store its path in Database while saving/editing/fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save the  video file itself to a SQL server.  Save the files to server or cloud storage and save only information related to the video in a SQL server such as title, size, uniqueID, etc.